# PostgreSQL JDBC Driver » 42.2.25 is compatible with postgresql 15.3 DB?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Nowadays I am using the version 42.2.25 of postgresql jdbc driver and I would like to know if is compatible with the postgresql version 15.3

Comment: The [documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/) states: _"The current version of the driver should be compatible with PostgreSQL® 8.2 and higher using the version 3.0 of the PostgreSQL® protocol, and it’s compatible with Java 8 (JDBC 4.2) and above."_. Do you have any particular concerns or problems? Or are you just second guessing this blanket statement?

Comment: I have not the current version of the driver I am using a specific version 42.2.25, I would like know if I can mantein this driver version an use the last version of postgresql 15.3

Comment: The beauty of versioning your connection protocol like PostgreSQL does, is that generally if there are new or breaking things, there would be a new protocol version, and a previous protocol version - assuming it's still supported - will work just fine (but just won't have access to the new thing that required a new protocol version). And if the old protocol version is no longer supported, you get an error informing you of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no official statement which JDBC driver version works with which PostgreSQL server version. The rule of thumb is that you should always use a driver version that was released *after* the server version. New drivers know how to speak to an old server, but not vice versa.

Since you want to support the latest released version, you should use the latest driver (42.6.0 at the time of writing). 4.2.25 is comparatively old. You can try it, but you risk running into bugs, and if you do, the first thing we'll tell you is that you should upgrade. So you may as well upgrade right away.